# Trying to simulate a birth death process

Tags: r

Question:

A birth and death process is a continuous time
Markov chain.

Find an approximative numerical value for the probability

P {max0≤t≤10 X(t) ≥ 10}

for a birth and death process {X(t)}t≥0

with birth intensities λ0 = λ1 = λ2 = . . . = 1

and death intensities µ1 = µ2 = µ3 = . . . = 2

that is in steady-state (that is, which is
started according to its stationary distribution).

My attempt at a solution:

```
rep = 100000

count = 0


for (i in 1:rep) {

   time = 0
   xt = 0
   succ = 0
   start = 0

   u.rand = runif(1)

   # These if statements determine where we start 
   # according to the stationary distribution

   if (u.rand<1/2) {start = 0}                   

   if (1/2<=u.rand && u.rand<3/4) {start = 1}

   if (3/4<=u.rand && u.rand<7/8) {start = 2}

   if (7/8<=u.rand && u.rand<15/16) {start = 3}

   if (15/16<=u.rand && u.rand<31/32) {start = 4}

   if (31/32<=u.rand && u.rand<63/64) {start = 5}

   if (63/64<=u.rand && u.rand<127/128) {start = 6}

   if (127/128<=u.rand && u.rand<255/256) {start = 7}

   if (255/256<=u.rand && u.rand<511/512) {start = 8}

   if (511/512<=u.rand && u.rand<1023/1024) {start = 9}

   if (1023/1024<=u.rand) {start = 10}

   # xt is the position during the while loop
   # and its a success if xt gets bigger than 10 

   xt = start                                          

   while ((time<=10) && (succ==0)) {

    mu = rexp(1, 2)                                   # death rate
    la = rexp(1, 1)                                   # birth rate


    # Here we get a birth and xt increases by 1.
    if (la<mu) {                                      

    xt = xt + 1

    time = time + la

    # Here we get a death as long as xt not is equal to 0

    } else if ((mu<la) && (xt!=0)) {                 

    xt = xt - 1

    time = time + mu

    # at xt=0 we can only get births

     } else if (xt==0) {                               

     xt = xt + 1

     time = time + la }


      # Here we register the successes.

      if (xt>=10) {succ = 1}                              

}

count = count + succ                  # And here we add them up

}

count/rep                                             

# And this frequency should be equal to
# the sought after probability
```

I get count/rep = 0.00615 but it should be 0.0084865

Something is wrong in my code.

Can anyone help me out?

Im pretty sure im doing something wrong in the while-loop.

Comment: Please give a full reference. I haven't the *faintest* idea what "G-S's book" might be. If you'd written G & S I might have guessed Grimmett and Stirzaker, but even then it would only be a guess and there are no doubt other possibilities. Please don't make people guess. We're not mindreaders.

Comment: Yes, its Grimmett and Stirzaker, I should have left that part out. I stated the problem as it is written and including Grimmett and Stirzaker was unnecessary. You dont need to know it is Grimmett and Stirzaker. You only need to know its a birth and death process with the specified birth and death rates and which probability im looking to simulate.

Comment: I removed that part now.

Comment: If you're quoting part of a book, you do need to include the full reference. See the policy on [referencing](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). You would also need to include the `self-study` tag (and read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info),  if necessary modifying your question as described). However, it appears as if you're simply asking for help with coding, in which case your post seems to be off-topic, as discussed in the [on topic help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (see under Programming). ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... If you believe it's on topic in spite of that, you'd need to edit to clarify in accordance with that policy.

Comment: @Glen_b This particular question does not seem to appear in Grimmett & Stirzaker so I don't think there is any need to reference G&S. Perhaps the OP can confirm this? I believe this question is on-topic, as there are some underlying statistical reasons as to why the OP did not get the answer they were expecting.

Comment: Yes, i dont think this question is from G & S. It was only included in the question because you could look up the equation for the stationary distribution there. Should i include self-study tag even if its not homework?                                                                                           Yes if you fully understand the underlying statistical/stochastical analysis of this question the coding should be pretty straight forward and therefore on-topic. But i admit i didnt know you couldnt post coding questions here.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandung the connection to Grimmet&Stirzaker. $\,$ 1. What *is* the source of the question? $\:$  2. "self-study" is not the same as "homework". It's for any routine question that would typically be found in a textbook, set as an exercise, be likely to be found in past papers or otherwise used for the purpose of study (rather than as an actual question related to applying statistics to a situation faced by the poster); this is clear in the description at the tag wiki. I'll leave it to you whether it applies. The main present issue is the coding one ... ctd

Comment: ctd... : your characterization of the coding as "straightforward" doesn't make it on topic. There needs to be a central statistical problem you're asking about. If your question is basically "what's wrong with my code" it's probably not on topic. I left it open in the hope that you'd follow my suggestion to edit; as it stands now I must put it on hold. You have an opportunity to edit to make it clearly on topic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure that 0.0085 is the correct answer? Looking at [here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/Stat/Grundutb/GU/MSG800/A14/Exercises/ExercisesGS.ps) suggests otherwise???

Some comments about your code:

(1) I think your code is essentially doing the right thing. However, the structure of the code within your while loop makes it difficult to read. I would split up the code into two 'if' clauses, i.e. if(xt==0) {...} and if(xt!=0) {...}, reflecting the special nature of the xt==0 situation, so that it is clear what actions are performed for these two different cases.

(2) Be careful as it is possible that 'time' may exceed 10 in your while loop, so you would need to ask that time<=10 as well as xt>=10 in order to register a success.

(3) u.rand>=1023/1024 corresponds to the situation where start>=10. Surely in these cases success is already guaranteed i.e. you should set succ=1.

(4) The statements about u.rand could be combined into a for loop, which would save typing time and reduce the risk of typing error.

(5) Running your code more than once reveals substantial between-run variability. You could reduce this by increasing 'rep'. Even better, you could stratify your sampling of the stationary distribution, as at the moment your use of 'runif' is introducing additional variability into your answers. To stratify, you could start by specifying rep=1024 (for example), then for the first 512 reps set start=0, for the next 256 reps set start=1, and so on.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Im learning a lot!. Doing the first 3 of your suggestions and increasing rep give me the result P = 0.0064 and that is the solution you are linking to. But i was under the impression the simulation on this page was correct and there the answer is 0.0085. [Simulation link](http://www.math.chalmers.se/Stat/Grundutb/GU/MSG800/A14/Exercises/ComputerExerciseGS.pdf)

Comment: And he is doing something different than me there, i dont understand what tho...and therefore i was thinking my solution was totally wrong...so im a bit confused. (Now im also trying to change my code according to your comments 4 and 5 which surely will improve it(but not change it so it looks like the linked solution though))

Comment: @JKnecht I don't fully understand the code you linked to in your comment - written in Wolfram I think. It's certainly much more difficult to read than your code, but I think that it is basically doing the same thing that your code is doing, and all of the points (1)-(5) in my answer apply to that code as well. I wouldn't worry about trying to get 0.0085 as it's not clear that this is the correct answer. Instead I would focus on understanding your code and making it as efficent as possible.